# Access SQL query missing more required parameters

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

In a web project, I'm trying to execute the following query:

```
SELECT ItemName as Name,
       ItemPicture as Picture,
       ItemHeroModif as Assistance,
       ItemTroopModif as Charisma,
       HerbCost as Herbs,
       GemCost as Gems
FROM Item WHERE ItemId = @value0
```

With breakpoints, I can see I attached to `@value0` the value, `2`.

Despite this, I get the following error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

I understood this error is usually generated due to bad SQL syntax. Is there anything wrong with what I did?

**EDIT**:

Attachment code:

```
var madeForCommand = "SELECT ItemName as Name,ItemPicture as [Picture],ItemHeroModif as Assistance,ItemTroopModif as Charisma, HerbCost as Herbs, GemCost as Gems FROM Item WHERE ";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
for (int ii = 0; ii < items.Count; ii++)// items is a list of items with IDs I want to get from the query.
{
    madeForCommand += "ItemId =@value"+ii+" OR ";   
}
madeForCommand = madeForCommand.Substring(0, madeForCommand.Length - 4); // making sure I trim the final or; In the case I shown, it's just one item, so there are none at all.
```

And later on:

```
OleDbCommand forOperations = new OleDbCommand(madeForCommand, _dbConnection); //_dbConnection is the connection to the database, it seems to work pretty well.
for (int ii = 0; ii < items.Count; ii++) 
{
    string attach = "@value" + ii;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(attach, items[ii].ID);
}
```

I'm pretty sure `items[ii].ID` is fine, breakpoints show that it equals 2 and the attachment goes well.

**EDIT 2**:
I've editted the code as Krish and Hans advised me, and I get the following query without any attachments:

```
SELECT ItemName as [Name],ItemPicture as Picture,ItemHeroModif as Assistance,ItemTroopModif as Charisma, HerbCost as Herbs, GemCost as Gems FROM [Item] WHERE (ItemID in (2));
```

I still get the same error, if it changes anything.

**EDIT 3**:
Executing the query in Access asks me to give a value to the parameter "ItemPicture"... Odd; ItemPicture is a column, isn't it?

Comment: Post the code where your set the value.

Comment: Can you please post the code where you set `@value0` to `2`? That is probably the problem. Also, sometimes you set a parameter to `null` and get the same error.

Comment: @Kobi Editted with the code.

Comment: You should try running the query directly in MS Access. If you for example misspell a column name, Access thinks it's a parameter. So make certain all your column names are spelt correctly.

Comment: you can also convert 'items' into a comma separated string and pass that in to SQL instead of using a for loop. i was always told not to use loops to do multiple individual queries. to do this, use a query similar to what @krish used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Name`, `Item`, and `Picture` are [problem words](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html) in Access queries.  Enclose them in square brackets:

```sql
SELECT ItemName as [Name], ItemPicture as [Picture], ItemHeroModif as Assistance, ItemTroopModif as Charisma, HerbCost as Herbs, GemCost as Gems
FROM [Item] WHERE ItemID in (2);
```

Since bracketing those names still gave you a missing parameter complaint, I asked you to test that query in Access' query designer.  In that context, Access presents a parameter input box which also includes the word which Access interprets as a parameter.

You reported Access thinks *ItemPicture* is a parameter.  So by inspecting that table in Access Design View, you discovered the actual field name is *ItemImageURL*.

```sql
SELECT ItemName as [Name], ItemImageURL as [Picture], ItemHeroModif as Assistance, ItemTroopModif as Charisma, HerbCost as Herbs, GemCost as Gems
FROM [Item] WHERE ItemID in (2);
```

Comment: Good point, I've got such mistakes in the past - However, this did not solve the problem, I get the same error message :/

Comment: I didn't notice `Picture`.  Please try again.

Comment: Can you test that query from the query designer in Access?

Comment: It asks me to provide a value to "ItemPicture".... That might be a key in solving the problem; Does that give you any ideas?

Comment: Absolutely!  Now try `SELECT ItemPicture FROM [Item];`  Still same error?

Comment: Yes, same error; I feel like this is getting somewhere... Dont forget to explain to me what's going on if you want your bounty. (:

Comment: OK. Your *Item* table does not include a field named *ItemPicture*.  Since you're in Access, inspect that table in Design View and check the column name.  Perhaps it includes a space ... *Item Picture*

Comment: Wooooohooooo, on point! I'll award you once I can. One last question - why did you execute this `SELECT ItemPicture FROM [Item];` specific query to test? out of curiousity.

Comment: That was just a quick test to verify my assumption that was the problem name.  What is the correct field name?

Comment: ItemImageURL... heh. I changed it once I changed the images to links... speaking of which, any idea why would access draw URLs and hyperlinks from queries like these with the # character in the start and end of the result, or alternativley, how I can turn them with the `#` marks into images?

Comment: If you're talking about a field whose Access datatype is "hyperlink", Access stores those values with `#` between the link components ... Url, display text, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76787/discussion-between-a-abramov-and-hansup).

Answer (score 2):

You are not taking the Where condition from outside your application so string concatenation is safe. (at least i think so)

just add the parameters like this:

```
var madeForCommand = "SELECT ItemName as Name,ItemPicture as Picture,ItemHeroModif as Assistance,ItemTroopModif as Charisma, HerbCost as Herbs, GemCost as Gems " +
    "FROM Item WHERE (ItemID in (";
     OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
     for (int ii = 0; ii < items.Count; ii++)// items is a list of items with IDs I want to get from the query.
     {
          if (i<=1) {
              madeForCommand += items[ii].ID
          }else {
              madeForCommand += "," + items[ii].ID;
          }
     }
    madeForCommand += "))"
```

at the end you will have a SQL query something like:

```
"SELECT ItemName as Name,ItemPicture as Picture,ItemHeroModif as Assistance,ItemTroopModif as Charisma, HerbCost as Herbs, GemCost as Gems " +
"FROM Item WHERE (ItemID in (1,2,3))";
```

Comment: That does compile, and I get a fine query - `SELECT ItemName as Name,ItemPicture as Picture,ItemHeroModif as Assistance,ItemTroopModif as Charisma, HerbCost as Herbs, GemCost as Gems FROM Item WHERE (ItemID in (2));` - despite this, I get the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

MS Access does not know parameters like this: `@value0`!

Use `?` instead or [named parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208916%28v=office.12%29.aspx) as follow:

```
PARAMETERS [value0] INT;
SELECT ItemName as Name,
       ItemPicture as Picture,
       ItemHeroModif as Assistance,
       ItemTroopModif as Charisma,
       HerbCost as Herbs,
       GemCost as Gems
FROM Item WHERE ItemId = [value0];
```

How to call this query? Please read this: [Accessing Microsoft Office Data from .NET Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971514.aspx)
For further information, see this: [OleDbCommand.Parameters Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**[EDIT]**

As per my understanding, you want to pass several `ItemId`'s into query. So, you have to use [IN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177907%28v=office.12%29.aspx) clause:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ItemID IN (1, 2, 5, 8)
```

Comment: I see.... However, as you can see from my code, I make the query dynamically. How would I do that with such syntax? 

I made similar queries before, its just that this one doesn't seem to work....

Comment: As i mentioned in my answer, you can use non-named parameters via using `?`: `WHERE ItemId = ?` ;)

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you mean... I looked up parameters in google, but I have no idea how the syntax goes ( this is not the way I used to do queries); Can you give me a simple example so it'll be easier for me the do such things in the future? Thanks in advance!

Comment: And how do i attach these values dynamically? Can I use AddWithValue()?

Comment: No. You have to build query string inside `for-next` loop. Without parameters.

Comment: I've changed the code, and I currently get the following query: `SELECT ItemName as Name,ItemPicture as Picture,ItemHeroModif as Assistance,ItemTroopModif as Charisma, HerbCost as Herbs, GemCost as Gems FROM Item WHERE (ItemID in (2));` yet - I get the same error. any idea?